# is it possible to find files and filepaths by only using a hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, sha256

is it possible to find a file by only inputting a hash (preferably sha256) and getting a filepath?
its also ok if i can immediately delete the file.
im trying to make like some sort of virus scan, i know this is not  good way is but its good enough for me.

i hope is can go something like this:

```
hash = 'hash'

path = find_file(hash, C:)

print(path)
```

i know this is not the best explanation but i hope someone can help me out.
its a school project and the time is tight.

thanks!

Comment: no. you can read 5 millions files and hash 5 million files when read (one after the other) and compare 5million hashes to your given hash ... and then delete the 5million+1 file because it fits. It is not performant. You cannot "look for a file" by its hash performantly. beside that - your code ist erroneous python

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: This is not a good idea. A hash code is not guaranteed to be unique. There is a very real possibility that two or more file names would hash to the same value. If that happens, you could delete the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible if the files you are searching through already have a hash associated with them. If not, you would first have to create a hash from each file's data and then check to see if that hash value matched the hash you were looking for.